# CS 1001 (identifier expected) - Receipt of List model data by controller from ASP.NET view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

trying to send data from cshtml table to controller (asp.net).

- In the controller, when assigning fields, I get an error

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp([FromBody]List<Karta_Model> modelKarta, int liczbaDni)

List<Karta_Model> objKartaModel = new List<Karta_Model>();

 for (int i = 1; i <= liczbaDni; i++)
                {
                    var model = new Karta_Model()
                    {
 DzMiesiaca = modelKarta.[i].DzMiesiaca.Value,
 DzTygodnia = modelKarta.[i].DzTygodnia.Value,
                    }
objKartaModel.Add(model);
                 }
```

In this way I get data from the table

**.cshtml**

```
@using AppEcp.Models
@model List<Karta_Model>

@for (int nr_rows = 0; nr_rows < ViewBag.IloscDni; nr_rows++)
            {
                var nr_names = nr_rows + 1;

<input asp-for=[@nr_names].DzMiesiaca class="nrs_days" type="number" value="@nr_names" name="day_@nr_names" id="id_day_@nr_names" readonly />
<input asp-for=[@nr_names].DzTygodnia style="min-width:90px" class="inputtext" type="text" id="id_descday_@nr_names" value="@day" readonly />

}
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

**Error** (

> CS 1001 identifier expected

Appears on the first bracket near:

.[i]

**additional question:**
- Does it make sense, or else can I save the data from the model lists to the database?

- I need to take this entire list and add some more parameters from controller

removing a model from Lists and adding a model to the next list after removing it

for ex. piece of code from the controller

```
 var model = new Karta_Model()
{
 SthElse = SthElseFromSomeWhere
 DzMiesiaca = modelKarta.[i].DzMiesiaca.Value,
 DzTygodnia = modelKarta.[i].DzTygodnia.Value,

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting compiler error on syntax.
Try this code instead of yours:

```
DzMiesiaca = modelKarta[i].DzMiesiaca.Value,
DzTygodnia = modelKarta[i].DzTygodnia.Value,
```